# How to differentiate between JSON Web Tokens from API partner or tokens from my own front-end client?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, jwt

According to https://jwt.io, JSON Web Tokens should be passed via the following header:

`Authorization Bearer <token>`

I'd like to use JSON Web Tokens for my clients API keys as well.

If different secret keys are used for each client to encode the JSON Web Tokens, how am I supposed to know which secret key to use to decode the token? How do people normally handle this when using JSON Web Tokens for APIs?

I thought about using a single secret key for all requests, but that means if that key is ever compromised and I have to update it--ANYONE using my API has to come get a new web token.

Comment: Maybe a simple solution would be to add another header to the request that would tell you where the request came from so you could choose which key to decrypt with.  Or try to decode the first and if it fails, try to decode the second, kinda hacky tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think in two usage scenarios. In the fisrt one you issue the JWT after requiring credentials to Client, and a second one where client build the JWT and sign it with his secret key.

**Issuing JWT from server**

In this scenario, the service to issue a JWT validates the identity of the requestor, for example requiring user&password, previously provided.

The JWT will contain the Client identifier in `sub` (subject) claim. You can set `aud` (audience)  to stablish the usage context of the token to your API, and not front-end. Also you can set custom claims

All tokens are signed with the same key. It could be diffrent than the key used to sign front-end tokens. Use a key pair if you need that aClient validates the JWT

**Client issue JWT**

In this scenario, each client has their own secret, or if using assymetric keys,  has registered a public key which corresponds to a private key in their possession

The secret key has been generated and shared for example through a administration console

The `sub` claim of JWT identifies the principal that is the subject of the JWT. The server will validate the signature with the secret key /public key of the Client.

If you are using also JWT for your front-end, the `iss` (issuer) claim allow to distinguish tokens issued by you or issued by a third party

Note: JWT is defined in [RFC 7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519). Bearer tokens are recommended but they are not mandatory

Comment: Thanks for the info @pedrofb -- correct me if I'm wrong, but the `iss` would be me in both cases, since I issue the JWTs to not only my front-end but to API clients. Also, doesn't this still mean that if my own secret key is compromised (the one I generate the JWTs with), every single API key has to be reinstated?

Comment: or are you saying they have to supply their public key AND the JWT in the request? If so, how do they supply the public key alongside it?

Comment: I was talking about a scenario where client build the JWT and sign it with his secret key. The secret key has been generated and shared for example through a administration console. It could be used also to upload a public key. If your intended usage is not this, then my answer does not fit with your question

Comment: About you first comment, Are you calling "Client" to a final user, or to a partner that uses your API? In the second case, how are you planning to provide a.JWT to a partner? When you issue a JWT is expected that you validate the identity of the requestor, for example requiring user&password. Note that validating partner identity requires a different flow that validating a final user identity

Comment: these tokens would be generated by me, in the same manner if you signed up to use Stripe's API, you can grab your API keys (or regenerate them) from their dashboard. Client is a third party who uses our API

Comment: I have added in the answer your desired usage scenario issuing your own tokens